# Перенос тестового Airflow на продуктивный контур

Tags: postgresql, airflow

Мне нужно перенести тестовый Airflow на продуктивный контур и я не могу понять последовательность действий.

Первое что я сделал: замерджил тестовый гит лаб со всеми ДАГАми в продовый гит лаб. Все ДАГИ подтянулись на продовый Аирфлоу.

Вопрос: мне нужно делать Connection к БД(на тесте это PostreSQL), к которой подсоединен тестовый Airflow или к другой БД ?

Расскажите о ваших кейсах связанных с переносом Airflow.